# How to adjust mouse speed multiplier for multiple mice individually?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, trackball

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring Separate Accelerations for Mice (Per-Pointer Speeds)](https://superuser.com/questions/327788/configuring-separate-accelerations-for-mice-per-pointer-speeds)

I have a laptop with a Synaptics touchpad, a wireless Logitech laser mouse (USB) and an X-Gaming X-Arcade trackball (connected via USB).

The X-Arcade trackball is extremely slow compared to the touchpad and logitech mouse when it comes to pointer movement.

The Windows 7 mouse control panel doesn't allow me to adjust the speed of the mouse devices individually. Is there a way to adjust the speed multiplier based on the individual USB HID device? I'm guessing I have to edit something directly in the registry for this to work...

Answer (score 2):

Natively, this is impossible. You'll need third party software or software that came with your mice. And THAT is if the drivers even bother to support their own settings.  A lot of non-gaming mice just read the speed settings from the OS without allowing you to set a separate setting for the device itself. . .

**edit**

The Logitech should use its own Setpoint software.  There should be a setting that says something like "Use Native OS driver blah blah blah"  Turn that off to set a separate setting for the mouse.  I can't remember if the Synaptic trackpad has that similar setting.  I can find an answer by firing up my laptop, which has a Synaptic trackpad.