# Configuring Separate Accelerations for Mice (Per-Pointer Speeds)

Tags: windows, mouse, mouse-acceleration

I just got a USB mouse that is 1600 dpi, while my normal one is 800 dpi. As a result, when I move the new mouse, the cursor flies around the screen at double speed.

If I reduce the speed in the mouse control panel applet, then the new mouse works smoothly, but then the old one is slow and sluggish.

It seems that Windows is using the same speed settings for *all* pointer devices connected to the system, which of course is no good for this exact sort of reason.

Hoping that the mouse control-panel applet is merely an interface to the registry, I checked `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`, but it has only a single set of values for the speed and acceleration curve. I also checked the `CurrentControlSet` and found the settings that can be set for each pointer device via the Device Manager such as wheel-detection and packet-size, but nothing related to speed.

Is there a way to set the speed/acceleration for each pointer device individually?

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: Windows (hence *control panel*).

Comment: Did you know that the movement / distance travelled relationship of a mouse is measured in *mickeys* - I kid you not! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_%28computing%29#Mouse_speed

Comment: @Linker3000, as a matter of fact I *did* know that. I just pulled out my copy of *Microsoft Mouse Programmer’s Reference (2nd edition)*: “The motion of the mouse track ball translates into values that express the direction and duration of the motion. These values are given in a unit of distance called a *mickey*, which is approximately 1/200 inch (1/400 inch for a 400 ppi mouse). 
…”