# Alternative to setpoint that allows key configuration profiles for multiple mice?

Tags: drivers, hotkeys, logitech-mouse

I have 2 mice: Logitech MX Revolution and Razer DeathAdder.

I use my mx revolution for browsing internet (I set up a lot of hotkeys on all my buttons to make browsing really convenient) and the deathadder for gaming (the mouse is a lot more accurate and smooth).

The problem is that by having two mice, setpoint randomly forgets its settings once in a while (I'm assuming due to getting confused why theres two input devices), and I constantly have to restart setpoint (every few minutes) to get it to rerecognize that the

Comment: I agree about needing an alternative. I really don’t like having to install a bunch of software (SetPoint/IntelliPoint/etc.) to use the extended keys and buttons my keyboard and mouse. I have not seen the problem with SetPoint forgetting the settings due to two input devices, but I have noticed a problem with [multiple pointer devices of varying speeds](http://superuser.com/questions/327788/). It seems that Microsoft/Logitech/etc. just haven’t put much thought into their software in terms of multiple devices. `:-(`

Comment: I really wish the Saitek programming software would work for non-cybord/saitek devices, it's key binding profiles done right.

Comment: [Here's](http://superuser.com/questions/442165/make-the-middle-mouse-button-behave-as-a-double-click-in-windows-7) another complaint about SetPoint (and its ilk). It would be great if there were a lightweight third-party tool that could expose the enhanced functions of keyboards and mice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ultimate tool of them all. (enhances SetPoint possibilities)

> http://uberoptions.net/

[image]

Comment: Oh man this is awesome! Unfortunately my mx-revolution has died a year ago. Logitech no longer manufactures this mouse and is replacing it with someone that doesnt have a thumb scroll wheel nor a super scroll feature. :(

Answer (score 6):

Try the wonderful and free [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) :

> You are able to provide application or window specific mappings, which
>   means an application or window can use the mouse buttons differently
>   from another. For each profile you can optionally define up to 5
>   'layers' of different button configurations which you can switch
>   between using hotkeys or mouse buttons.

I am a user of X-Mouse Button Control, but I have no experience with using multiple mouses.
For questions or suggestions, don't hesitate to contact the developer.
When I did, he usually answered back in a few days.

[image]

Comment: Note: This product is incompatible with Setpoint, so you need to uninstall it first.

Comment: I can’t find anything about per-device settings, only app-specific settings.

Comment: This looks great. I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't recognize my side scroll wheel. The boxes are grayed out. I thought maybe it requires SetPoint, but then I read the comment above. What's wrong here?

Comment: This replaces and conflicts with SetPoint. You might try to get in touch with the developer.

Comment: It also allows you to scroll the window under the mouse, instead of always having to click to within a window before scrolling.  One of those little features that makes all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the past there has been development of such functionality in AutoHotKey, however I see no receent discussion and am unsure of the current status. Perhaps interested users can contribute (I will certainly take a look at some stage).

One script utilises a usb HID aware dll to separate the functionality, while at the same time disabling native calls to the mice.

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/26967-using-multiple-mice-to-control-one-computer/

Another was written explicitly to allow independent swapping of left/right buttons, I wonder if it could be extended to cover the OPs request.

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/44468-eithermouse-059-multiple-mice-individual-settings/

Incidentally this looks much more simpler to perform in Linux through Xinput.