# How to map custom Logitech keyboard keys on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, remapping, logitech-keyboard

I have Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse MK710. On Fedora I could map every key including a custom key that opens a CD tray, in fact I think all keys were mapped correctly by default. On Windows 10, that's not the case. I've downloaded every windows program/driver related to my keyboard, available on Logitech's website.

I've seen couple of keyboard mapping programs for windows, they say that they don't map custom Logitech keys and such, they only map keys that are supported by default in windows.

I've contacted Logitech, they told me to use their software called Setpoint, I tried but it only detects the [calculator key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8jnt.jpg). I replied telling  them them that their software didn't work, they ignored my second email.

Is it possible to map these custom keys? Currently the keys I want to map do nothing at all.

Comment: The latest SetPoint is now [version 8.96.88](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/downloads). Try also [this fix](https://yabb.jriver.com/interact/index.php?topic=25426.0). Otherwise, replace SetPoint by [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) ([useful link](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64875-mapping-special-keys/)).

Comment: Try one of these? https://superuser.com/questions/437815/alternative-to-setpoint-that-allows-key-configuration-profiles-for-multiple-mice

Comment: @rahuldottech my problem is keyboard not mouse

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT tried what you said yesterday, didnt work

Comment: @harrymc where can i find setpoint version you referred to? the version i have is the one i see on their site, 6.67.82

Comment: @Lynob try http://uberoptions.net/ It's also for keyboards

Comment: The version can be found from my link, but here is the [direct link](https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/mouse/SetPoint6.67.83_64.exe). The name of the download file is `SetPoint6.67.83_64.exe`, and this maybe means "version 6.7.83 64-bit".

Comment: did you try Microsoft keyboard and mouse center ? You can do some remap in there.:  https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/fr-ca/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center

Comment: @harrymc doesn't work

Comment: @LateGameReviewer the installer does not run, even in compatibility. it says error

Comment: @rahuldottech that works with an extremely old version of setpoint, and, not supported on my pc and the software is long dead anyway

Comment: the installer does not run, even in compatibility. it says error – Lynob
+++++
Did you take a look at the event viewer to know if it gave any info regarding the error ?

Comment: I think you will need to replace SetPoint by AutoHotkey. Let me know if this solution interests you.

Comment: Additional questions: Are the media keys the problem? Do they work well when Setpoint is not running?

Comment: @harrymc no just one or two buttons arent working as they should be but setpoint is useless since it's only detecting the calculator button out of all the buttons on my keyboard. autohotkey definitely interests me

Comment: Well shucks.... darn setpoint software and media keyboard keys not working as expected... AHK to the rescue!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setpoint is very bad on custom keys, and in addition it has the bad habit
of swallowing up some of these keys, such as the multimedia keys,
so they are unavailable to other programs.

I suggest to avoid Setpoint and to use instead
[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Your first step is to find out the scan-codes of the special keys.
Since we are using AutoHotkey, create a `.ahk` file, and enter and run the
following scriptlet
([source](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/21105-crazy-scripting-scriptlet-to-find-scancode-of-a-key/)):

```
SetFormat, Integer, Hex
Gui +ToolWindow -SysMenu +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, Font, s14 Bold, Arial
Gui, Add, Text, w100 h33 vSC 0x201 +Border, {SC000}
Gui, Show,, % "// ScanCode //////////"
Loop 9
  OnMessage( 255+A_Index, "ScanCode" ) ; 0x100 to 0x108
Return

ScanCode( wParam, lParam ) {
 Clipboard := "SC" SubStr((((lParam>>16) & 0xFF)+0xF000),-2) 
 GuiControl,, SC, %Clipboard%
}
```

Run it and when the GUI is in focus press a key and the scancode
will be displayed and copied to the clipboard in the format for using
as hotkey or with Send commands.

The scancodes can be used in a scriptlet.
For example, use the Browser multimedia key to run Firefox:

```
SC032::Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Once the scriptlet is complete, you may store it in the Startup
folder so it will run automatically with Windows.

You may need to search for command-line programs that can do the operations
you need. For example, sound can be controlled by the free
[NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

Comment: the autohotkey script is detecting all keys except the key i want, what to do in that case? like windows isn't reading the key to start with

Comment: Some keys are used by the keyboard firmware to modify the behavior of other keys. An example is the Fn key on most laptops. Unfortunately, such keys do not generate scancodes and so cannot be mapped.

Comment: [See this](http://the620guy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/20160223-6_-_Logitech_MK700MK710_Keyboard__M310_Mouse__Rec__New_Batts_7.jpg) all the keys are generating codes except the one  that ejects the cd tray on the top right, next to the calculator key. on linux it's working. everything is generating codes for autohotkey except this one

Comment: I understand, but if the key doesn't generate a scan-code then this is a problem with its firmware and cannot be solved. You may assign another key or combination for ejecting by using AutoHotkey and the utility NirCmd.

Answer (score 0):

As per others, changing the user.xml file that is written to

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Logitech\SetPoint
```

is the only way I could get it to work properly.

For example, for a Logitech K530 keyboard, I wanted to map the **Gadgets** key (top left) and the **Media Center** key (top right) to move applications to the monitor on the left/right.

I used the **SwitchMonitorLeft** and **SwitchMonitorRight** HandlerSets - other examples can be found in C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\default.xml file.

This is what worked for the **Gadgets** key:

```
<Button Number="589885" Name="Gadgets">
   <Param IconLoc="Devices\Keyboard\CommonIcons\Gadgets" Type="HOTKEY"/>
   <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
      <Param Button="589885" EventType="100663297" FirstRepeatDelay="0" RepeatDelay="0" Silent="0" Type="0"/>
      <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="SwitchMonitorLeft">
      </TriggerState>
   </Trigger>
</Button>
```

and this for the **Media Center** key:

```
<Button Number="12320781" Name="Media Player">
   <Param IconLoc="Devices\Keyboard\CommonIcons\mediacenternew" Type="HOTKEY"/>
   <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
      <Param Button="12320781" EventType="100663297" FirstRepeatDelay="0" RepeatDelay="0" Silent="0" Type="0"/>
      <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="SwitchMonitorRight">
      </TriggerState>
   </Trigger>
</Button>
```